# Winform datagridview combobox EF mapping error

Tags: winforms, entity, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am trying to make a picklist using the datagridview combobox, the list is dispalying properly but while selecting it is giving a type/casting error. It is giving string but expecting entity type  MyProduct.

Error Invalid cast from System.String to MyProduct

```
   private void frmtest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var products = new BindingList<MyProduct>()
        {
        new MyProduct(){ID =1,Name="Product1"       },
        new MyProduct(){ID =2,Name="Product2"       },
        new MyProduct(){ID =4,Name="Product3"       },
        new MyProduct(){ID =5,Name="Product4"       }

        };
        MyProduct.DataSource= products;//comboboxcolumn datasource

    }


public class MyProduct
{
    public MyProduct()
    {

    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Specification { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
public class MyPurchaseItem
{
    public MyPurchaseItem()
    {

    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual MyProduct MyProduct { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading various replies, managed to solve this issue by adding a method to return the same object.

This requires a nethod to return the object itself which can be assigned to ValueMember and then set displaymember.

```
public MyProduct()
    {

    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Specification { get; set; }
    ***public MyProduct Self { get { return this; }  }***
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

//datagridcombobox changed as below
        MyProduct.DataPropertyName = "MyProduct";
        MyProduct.ValueMember = "Self";
        MyProduct.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: It would be more simple if you include foreign keys in your model and  then bind combo box to `MyProductId`